# Magento 2 Adding custom parameter to the ajax url, from the admin grid row issue

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ajax

I am on the edit page with the following url:

```
https://local.magento/admin/hello_test/shipping/edit/shippingmethod_id/1/key/df70da11cddd2ee1c41aa67a8cbccf6d9403207740547719560dec30a3fd9ceb/
```

, where I loaded a custom grid. When I want to edit the **price** column and press the **save** button, I would like to pass to the ajax url an extra paramater, from the UI component XML.

[image]

This is what I tried:

```
    <columns name="my_columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">custom name</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</param>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="hello_test/Shipping/inlineEdit">
                        <param name="shippingmethod_id">{i would like here to include the shippingmethod_id value from my edit page url}</param>
                    </item>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
            </editorConfig>
....
```

In the `<param name="shippingmethod_id">` i can include static values(and it works), but i would like to include the value of the `shippingmethod_id` from the edit page url . Is that possible ? :)

Thnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add dynamic parameters to the url you can use many approaches, depending on your case:

1. Modify url in your dataprovider implementation `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProviderInterface::getMeta`
2. Modify url in component custom class (extending from `\Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns`)
3. Modify js component

But we have ability to pass all current url params to new url during url generation using param `_current`.
So in your case the easiest way - add param `_current` to url element

```xml
<item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="hello_test/Shipping/inlineEdit">
    <param name="_current">true</param>
</item>
```

Comment: Hmm .adding the `<param name="_current" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>`   part `Element 'param', attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type': The type definition 'boolean', specified by xsi:type, is blocked or not validly derived from the type definition of the element declaration.`

Comment: I removed this part: `xsi:type="boolean"` and it works. Not sure why :) Can you update your post with this feedback ? , so i can accept your answer

Comment: @AttilaNaghi Yes, sure. I have updated answer

Comment: Kudos for the solution @Max